# Homemade taffy turned out too thick and hard

Tags: dessert, taffy

I had found a recipe to make homemade Tootsie Rolls which was essentially just chocolate taffy.  I've tried it a few times with the same result; it turns into basically a somewhat chewy hard candy.

I'm not a candy making expert, but I think the problem might lie in either the heating of the mixture (ie- getting it to the right temp for the type of candy it is) or in the pulling.

Does that sound about right?  Are there other things that I can check when making taffy that would turn it into a soft rock?

Comment: It might take quite a lot of trial and error to approximate a Tootsie Roll at home. The method of making a Tootsie Roll is a closely guarded "trade secret".

Comment: @hobo: yes, I understand that.  Was more interested in what I did wrong to make just a general taffy turn into a chewy rock...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temperature is certainly important. If you start out with a hard candy straight from the pot you're gonna be largely out of luck regardless.

But really, the signature taffy texture comes from the continual pulling, folding, pulling that happens after you remove it from the heat. Pulling taffy works lots of air into it and stretches out the strands of sugar crystals into thinner, chewier shapes. So be sure you *really* work that taffy once you take it off the heat (and before cutting it).